# Recursive function returns None instead of string value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def uniqfile( title, suffix ):
    print('input: '+title)
    if os.path.isfile(title+suffix):
        title += " "
        uniqfile(title, suffix)
    else:
        return title+suffix
```

The first print line within it returns the correct output, but when the function is supposed to finally return the properly appended title value, it instead returns `None`.

How do I get the value returned properly so that I may assign it to a variable to print out and save the file uniquely named?

```
namepdf = uniqfile(row[0], '.pdf')
```

Comment: You forgot the return: `return uniqfile(title, suffix)`. Also google "Python recursive None" and the first hit are 5 duplicates on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to add the return statement. That's why you get `None`

```
def uniqfile( title, suffix ):
    print('input: '+title)
    if os.path.isfile(title+suffix):
        title += " "
        # put RETURN here
        return uniqfile(title, suffix)
    else:
        return title
```